# Show/hide multiple elements

Tags: jquery, dom

Having to control the visibility of a number of dom elements based on a number of logic checks - I really would like something like this in jquery:

```
$('.FirstPanel').visible = (condition == 1 || othercondition == true);
$('.SecondPanel').visible = (condition > 3 || othercondition == false);
$('.ThirdPanel').visible = (condition < 3 || stillanothercondition = 'asdf');
etc
```

Of course I can express the code above using if or switch statements and calling `$('.FirstPanel').hide()`...but it would require many times the number of lines of code.

```
if(condition == 1 || othercondition == true) {
    $('.FirstPanel').show();
    $('.SecondPanel').hide();
    $('.ThirdPanel').hide();
} else if (condition > 3 || othercondition == false) {
    $('.FirstPanel').hide();
    $('.SecondPanel').show();
    $('.ThirdPanel').hide();
} etc
```

I feel I'm missing something obvious.  Thanks

---

2012.09.24 Update

Thanks for the answers everyone - the toggle method is the ticket (see Michaël Witrant's accepted answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.FirstPanel').toggle(condition == 1 || othercondition == true);
$('.SecondPanel').toggle(condition > 3 || othercondition == false);
$('.ThirdPanel').toggle(condition < 3 || stillanothercondition = 'asdf');
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$(".element").css("display", function() { value = (condition == 1 || othercondition == true); if (value) { return 'block'; /*or 'inline' or 'inline-block'*/ } 
return 'none'; });
```